# Need to write my own Vector3.RotateTowards()

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

There is a Inbuilt function in Unity called [Vector3.RotateTowards](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html) ..

I tried writing this using CrossProduct then use Axis rotation. but didn't work.

I am wondering if anybody could write *Vector3.RotateTowards* for me.

Comment: So what's wrong with RotateTowards, Slerp, SmoothDamp,... ?

Comment: @Kay, actually i just wanted to create my own function, to just learn how engine is doing this. Actually i m not a good physics student, but know a little bit.

Comment: a good place to start is transform.LookAt();